Keycloak v19 create flow not creating authenticationExecutions
I was trying to create a new flow and executions with the keycloak API but only the flow is created with execution being empty.
The url im using: POST: keycloak-url/auth/admin/realms/realmName/authentication/flows
When I try to get the flows,I can see the browser-2fa-email new flow, but  authenticationExecutions is an empty array. What am I doing wrong here?
Request Body:
    "alias": "browser-2fa-email",
    "description": "browser based authentication 2FA",
    "providerId": "basic-flow",
    "topLevel": true,
    "builtIn": false,
    "authenticationExecutions": [
            {
                "authenticator": "auth-cookie",
                "authenticatorFlow": false,
                "requirement": "ALTERNATIVE",
                "priority": 10,
                "autheticatorFlow": false
            },
            {
                "authenticator": "identity-provider-redirector",
                "authenticatorFlow": false,
                "requirement": "ALTERNATIVE",
                "priority": 25,
                "autheticatorFlow": false
            },
            {
                "authenticatorFlow": true,
                "requirement": "ALTERNATIVE",
                "priority": 30,
                "autheticatorFlow": true,
                "flowAlias": "forms"
            }
        ]
}```



